# Build war with maven plus a jar with a subset of classes

Tags: maven

By default I am building a war in the standard way.

However, I also need to export a collection of java classes to a JAR to share for legacy reasons.  Is there an easy way to do this?

**Update:**
To clarify, in addition to the default WAR output and layout I need a JAR that contains:

```
{project.base}/src/main/java*
{project.base}/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/).

Keep `<packaging>war</packaging>` and `maven-war-plugin` (if you have defined in your pom) and add `maven-jar-plugin` to your `<build>` configuration, defining your custom class inclusions/exclusions.

Example excluding class `A` and all classes of package `pkg` of builded jar:

```
   ...
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   ...
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>jar</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <excludes>
                        <exclude>A.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>pkg/**</exclude>
                     </excludes>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

As output, when you build the project with maven, you will have a `war` and a `jar` (without excluded classes) in your output directory.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use maven-war-plugin with the appropriate configuration which is supported by [maven-war-plugin out of the box](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses):

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The above configuration will create an supplemental artifact which contains the classes from `src/main/java`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

which you can use in other projects.

Comment: This is awesome, almost does what I need, it turns out the META-INF stuff doesn't get thrown into the JAR